# Get Updates from Twitter using API from the given Date

Tags: twitter-oauth, twitter-rest-api

Is there is any API available in twitter to get the updates after the given date?
For example.
If i give the date as 18 jan 2016 then,My expected the result is the collection of twitter Updates which happens after 18th Jan 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. Most API calls take the optional parameter `since_id`. The call will then only result items with an id greater than the one specified. That also means they're newer.

Comment: thanks.this works fine for user_timeline.But for the API( https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json - To get followers list) since id was not working.Seems since and max_id were not supported in These list API's (Friends list,Followers list etc)....In such cases,how to get the followers list which was followed after the given date / id ?....